# Getting a byte array instead of saving a byte array as a file

Tags: c#, arrays, storage

I'm getting a raw varbinary data from an SQL server.
Firstly I'm saving it as a file, because I am loading the file and drawing a series of points on a chart. But now I also want to save it to another server when a user clicks on a button.
It's terribly stupid to:

1. Load binary data from server
2. 'Convert' to a file
3. Save it to a path
4. Load from this path.
5. Draw a chart.
6. Load from this path
7. Save to server.

When I could be doing:

1. Load binary data from server
2. 'Convert' to Byte[] or some other kind of array.
3. Draw a chart from this array
4. Save this array to a server.

I think it needs to be a byte array though, as the server I'm loading from and the server I'm saving to has the datatype varbinary(max). I've attached an image of what exactly I wish the program to be doing.

So my question: **Stop saving to a path using BinaryWriter, and start getting a byte[] I can use several times**

This is the part where I think it saves to the given filepath.

```
string fullPath = C:/Users/Mathias/Documents/Lektier/IHA/3. Semester/Projekt/Temporary Blob + "/" + fileName;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fs);
            CurrentIndex = 0;
            BytesReturned = reader.GetBytes(1, CurrentIndex, Blob, 0, BufferSize);
            while (BytesReturned == BufferSize)
            {
                writer.Write(Blob);
                writer.Flush();
                CurrentIndex += BufferSize;
                BytesReturned = reader.GetBytes(1, CurrentIndex, Blob, 0, BufferSize);
            }

            writer.Write(Blob, 0, (int)BytesReturned);

            writer.Flush(); writer.Close();
        }
```

[image: My drawing skills are subpar]

If you want the full source code for this form, please do ask. It's just kind of messy right now, so I didn't see the point of pasting the whole thing.

Comment: the important bit is can whatever you are using to draw the chart accept some other argument than filename...

Comment: hehe it does. I'm converting the byte[] to a string, then splitting the string for every line in it ('\n')
Then I store it in a string array, and run a foreach for every string in that string[] and add a point to a series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you should just be writing to a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx):

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
long bytesRead;
long index = 0;
while ((bytesRead = reader.GetBytes(1, index, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, (int) bytesRead);
    currentIndex += bytesRead;
}
byte[] data = stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: This seems very right! 
I'm trying this code out, and I'm getting this at the while loop;
Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
I'm choosing the correct column and there definitely is data present.
My reader:

SqlDataReader reader = LoadCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

My command:

SqlCommand LoadCmd = new SqlCommand("Select ekgmaaleid,raa_data,borger_fornavn,borger_efternavn,borger_beskrivelse,borger_cprnr,dato,maaleformat_type,fil_navn from EKG_Temp where fil_navn = @fil_navn", GlobalVariables.con);

Comment: Haha silly. I never set the reader to actually read. Solved. Thank you for this, friend.